# Civ 4 mod, choose your opponents

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

Can anyone direct me to a mod that allows me to select my opponent civilizations and leaders when beginning a game?

Comment: You don't need a mod for that, you can do that just by starting a custom game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need any mod to do that, you just need to start a custom game:

[image: solo game menu]

You can then select the number of opponents, their leader and civilisation and setup teams, among many other options.

[image: custom game screen]